# Spring webflux / Project reactor - how to write data from flux to text file

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to write to a text file the information returned in a flux by the web client.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("ex1.txt", "UTF-8");

webClient.get().uri("/users/listall")
.retrieve()
.bodyToFlux(Students.class).map( stud ->{
    return stud.getName() + ", " + stud.getAge();
}).subscribe(writer::write);

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

I know for a fact that all data is properly obtained because if I replace

```
.subscribe(writer::write);
```

with

```
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

everything is shown as intended.

I have also tried writing something before flushing to make sure that was not the problem and it wrote as intended that extra message, but nothing from the flux, which leads me to believe that I cannot write to the file like that.

What is the best way to write this without compromising the nonblocking properties of the webflux?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `PrintWriter` is a blocking API which is not recommended to use with reactor. Ususally if we need to use some blocking API, then we wrap it with `Mono.fromCallable()` and switch the execution to another thread, `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

There is approach that I use sometimes when work with files.
It not "truly" reactive way to write lines in file, but asyncronous and it is still better than using some standard blocking API. This approch underhood uses `AsynchronousFileChannel` from `java.nio` package. Example:

```
webClient.get()
            .uri("/users/listall")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Students.class)
            .map(student -> student.getName() + ", " + student.getAge())
            .transform(this::writeRows)
            .subscribe();

Thread.sleep(10_000L); // just for testing purposes as we immediately return after subscribe()
```

And the actual method for writing rows to file. It transforms the rows to DataBuffers and writes them to AsynchronousFileChannel:

```
public Mono<Void> writeRows(Flux<String> rowsFlux) {
    DefaultDataBufferFactory bufferFactory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
    CharSequenceEncoder encoder = CharSequenceEncoder.textPlainOnly();

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = rowsFlux.map(line ->
            encoder.encodeValue(line, bufferFactory, ResolvableType.NONE, null, null)
    );
    return DataBufferUtils.write(
            dataBufferFlux,
            Path.of("/your_path_to_save_file/file.txt"),
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW
    );
}
```

Also you might need to write every string on a new line, then just explicitly add `+ "\n"` in the end of your string

Answer (score -1):

Subscribe is asynchronous. It means that once called, it returns immediately, and process values concurrently in another thread(s).

So, with your current snippet, you flush and close your writer immediately after *starting* processing. If you add a `Thread.sleep(2000);` just before `writer.flush()`, it will give time to the pipeline to process elements and send them to the writer.

Obviously, the delay depends on the time required to process your data.

### Test

Let's simulate it with a snippet that create hard-coded students and send them in a delayed fashion:

```java
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.Duration;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class ReactivePrintWriter {

    record Student(String name, int age) {}

    public static Flux<Student> fetchStudents() {
        return Flux.just(
                        new Student("John", 19),
                        new Student("Arthur", 21),
                        new Student("Alice", 18)
                )
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(50));
    }

    public static void writeAndWaitFor(long timespanMillis) throws Exception {
        final Path outputFile = Files.createTempFile("test", ".txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputFile.toFile(), "UTF-8");

        fetchStudents()
                .map( stud -> stud.name() + ", " + stud.age())
                .subscribe(writer::println);

        Thread.sleep(timespanMillis);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("-> Waited for "+timespanMillis+" ms");
        Files.readAllLines(outputFile).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        writeAndWaitFor(90);
        writeAndWaitFor(200);
    }
}
```

Above example sends a student approximately every 50 milliseconds. In the main function, we repeat the fetch and write two times, one time waiting less than 100 milliseconds, and another one more than a 100 milliseconds.

We see that the more we wait, the more we receive elements:

```
-> Waited for 90 ms
John, 19
-> Waited for 200 ms
John, 19
Arthur, 21
Alice, 18
```

### Improvements

Now, the next step: to make your code robust, it is possible to make two things:

1. Synchronize your writer lifecycle with the processor/request lifecycle. To do so, you can use *Flux.using* or *Mono.using* operator. It will open/close your writer upon subscription/completion of your request.
2. Make your data pipeline repeatable, by moving the writing away from subscribe, making it a part of the pipeline instead of a side-effect

If we rework above example to do that, it gives something like that:

```java
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.util.function.Tuple2;
import reactor.util.function.Tuples;

public class ReactivePrintWriter {

    record Student(String name, int age) {}

    public static Flux<Student> fetchStudents() {
        return Flux.just(
                        new Student("John", 19),
                        new Student("Arthur", 21),
                        new Student("Alice", 18)
                )
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(50));
    }

    public static Mono<Tuple2<Path, Long>> fetchWriteCount() {
        Callable<Tuple2<Path, PrintWriter>> initResource = () -> {
            var outputFile = Files.createTempFile("test", ".txt");
            var writer = new PrintWriter(outputFile.toFile(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return Tuples.of(outputFile, writer);
        };

        Function<Tuple2<Path, PrintWriter>, Mono<Tuple2<Path, Long>>> processResource = resource -> {
            var file = resource.getT1();
            var writer = resource.getT2();
            return fetchStudents()
                    .map( stud -> stud.name() + ", " + stud.age())
                    .reduce(0L, (count, stud) -> { writer.println(stud); return count + 1; })
                    .map(count -> Tuples.of(file, count));
        };

        Consumer<Tuple2<Path, PrintWriter>> closeResource = resource -> {
            var writer = resource.getT2();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        };

        return Mono.using(initResource, processResource, closeResource);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tuple2<Path, Long> result = fetchWriteCount().block();

        Path file = result.getT1();
        long count = result.getT2();

        System.out.printf("Written %d students in file: %s%n", count, file);
        Files.readAllLines(file).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));

        // We can re-execute the entire pipeline safely:
        result = fetchWriteCount().block();

        file = result.getT1();
        count = result.getT2();

        System.out.printf("Written AGAIN %d students in file: %s%n", count, file);
        Files.readAllLines(file).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line));
    }
}
```

This program prints:

```
Written 3 students in file: /tmp/test7077571472179039053.txt
John, 19
Arthur, 21
Alice, 18
Written AGAIN 3 students in file: /tmp/test12846142808116973618.txt
John, 19
Arthur, 21
Alice, 18
```